# Rails tag syntax with multiple data attribute values quotes excluded

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to generate

```
<img data-interchange="[assets/img/interchange/small.jpg, small], [assets/img/interchange/medium.jpg, medium], [assets/img/interchange/large.jpg, large]">
```

is challenging.

```
<%= tag "img", data: { interchange: ["[#{photo.image_url(:base).to_s}, small]", "[#{photo.image_url(:big).to_s}, medium]", "[#{photo.image_url(:desktop).to_s}, large]"] } %>
```

will generate HTML, but the result is still inoperative

```
<img data-interchange="[&quot;[https://[...]base_20160529_115006.jpg, small]&quot;,&quot;[https://[...]big_20160529_115006.jpg, medium]&quot;,&quot;[https://[...]desktop_20160529_115006.jpg, large]&quot;]"  />
```

as `&quot;` gets generated.

What is the proper syntax to get the proper HTML string

Comment: I've used JSON in `data-*` attributes before -- might that work for this use case?

Comment: Could be... but not in the hands of this JSON ignoramus...

Answer (score 0):

In rails you can use ActiveSupport's `to_json` to encode things into json.

```
<%= tag "img", data: { interchange: [[photo.image_url(:base), 'small'], [photo.image_url(:big), 'medium'], [photo.image_url(:desktop), 'large']].to_json } %>
```

Which produces

```
<img data-interchange="[[\"assets/images/interchange/base.jpg\",\"small\"],[\"assets/images/interchange/big.jpg\",\"medium\"],[\"assets/images/interchange/desktop.jpg\",\"large\"]]" />
```

Then on the front-end you can use `JSON.parse` once you retrieve the value via `getAttribute` or with jQuery `data`, if you need to use the data on the front-end.

```
var text = JSON.parse(element.getAttribute('data-interchange'));
```